# Trigger change event of a worksheet with activated edited cell in a shape/button click event

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with a clickable shape and a class listening to the change events of that sheet:

Sheet1:

```
Public Sub Shape_click()
  Debug.Print "click"
End Sub
```

Class1:

```
Private WithEvents sh As Worksheet

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set sh = Sheet1
End Sub

Private Sub sh_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Debug.Print "change: " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

When I edit a cell in Sheet1 and click directly on the shape the output is

```
click
change: $B$1
```

I would like to trigger the change event in the shape macro so that the change event would occur before printing "click". DoEvents, Sleep from kernel32 and activation of some other cell from the Shape_click were not working for me.

Comment: maybe activecell.calculate

Comment: `ActiveCell.Calculate` is not working for me, change is also triggered after the `Debug.Print`

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier I have found a better solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found two "hacks", the first one quite limited, but the second one does the job:

1. `Selection.Cut`:

   ```
   Public Sub Shape_click()
     Selection.Cut Selection
     Debug.Print "click"
   End Sub
   ```

   It makes the Change event to fire 3 times (2x before "click", 1x after that), every time with the right (changed) value.

   Of course you need to check the `Selection` (if it is set, if it's of `Range` type etc.)

   The solution is quite limited as you can't use it with merged cells in the selection (will ask if you want to unmerge them).
2. `Selection.Value = Selection.Value`

   ```
   Public Sub Shape_click()
     Selection.Value = Selection.Value
     Debug.Print "click"
   End Sub
   ```

   Works even with merged cells. There is also need to check `Selection` if it really contains a range.

Comment: the simples solution is to put the change sub in a normal modul in a sub, that you call in change, and also before the print. This way its clean